# Selenium chromedriver not playing nice with at_exit

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, rspec, atexit

Is this a bug in my code, or a bug in Selenium, RSpec, etc.?

The Cucumber tests I'm writing need to shut down and re-launch the Chrome driver.  However, I can't get this second driver to shut down properly.  The stripped-down example below shows the problem:  (The code below is RSpec only because it demonstrates the issue without adding the complexity of Cucumber.)

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

RSpec.configure do |config|
       config.before(:suite) do
           $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
         end
     end

describe "A potential rspec/selenium/chrome driver bug" do 
  it "doesn't play nice with at_exit" do    
    # quit the initial driver and start a new one.
    $driver.quit
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome    
  end # it
end # end describe

at_exit do
  $driver.quit
end
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
```

I can tell that the second chromedriver process no longer running when the `at_exit` block runs. This causes a problem because whatever mechanism is causing the shutdown is leaving the Chrome window open.

RSpec's `after(:suite)` mechanism works as expected.  Is there a corresponding mechanism for Cucumber (other than `at_exit`, which isn't working in this case)?  Or, is there a way to prevent chomedriver from exiting before the `at_exit` block runs (so I can shut it down using the `quit` method as expected)?

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OS 10.9.5 using the latest selenium and rspec packages.

Comment: The code runs as expected with the Safari and Firefox drivers.  I get the same error running this code with the Chrome driver in CentOS Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bug in my code.  The driver needs to be created before `env.rb` defines its own `at_exit` hook.  Here's why:

A typical `env.rb` for cucumber looks like this:

```
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-cache --ignore-certificate-errors]

at_exit do
  $driver.quit
end
```

The code that creates the driver object (`Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome`) also registers an `at_exit` hook that shuts down the `chromedriver` process.

`at_exit` hooks run in the opposite order they were created.  Therefore, a typical execution of cucumber looks like this:

1. `env.rb` creates a new driver
2. Driver defines `at_exit` hook to quit itself
3. `env.rb` defines `at_exit` hook to quit driver
4. Cucumber features run
5. `at_exit` hook from `env.rb` is called
6. Driver's `at_exit` hook is called

In my case, I created a driver inside a cucumber feature, which caused the driver's `at_exit` hook to be defined after the `at_exit` hook in `env.rb`.  As a result, the driver's `at_exit` hook runs first, causing the call to `$driver.quit` in `env.rb` to fail.

The best solution in this case is to create a second driver when necessary and destroy that second driver at the end of the scenario (as opposed to replacing the primary driver with a new one).

Thanks to Alex Rodionov for pointing out my mistakes.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/742